# Ajax update css of HTML elements

Tags: php, css, ajax, jquery

I want display and hide HTML div with ajax,

Situation:

```
progressbar('on');

very_long_function(); 

progressbar('off');
```

I want display div when working `very_long_function();` , bUt when finish working I want hide div

Progress bar function:

```
function progressbar($status){

    if($status == "on"){


        echo "
                <script> 
                        $(document).ready(function() {   function() { 
                        $('#load').css('display','inline');

                        }); 
                </script>
            ";
    } 
    else{

        echo "
                <script> 
                        $$(document).ready(function() {   function() { 
                        $('#load').css('display','none');

                        }); 
                </script>
            ";
    }
}
```

Problem is that div not showing when `very_long_function();` working, maybe is possible to solve this priblem with AJAX or jQuery

HTML

```
<div id="load" style="display: none;"><img src="loading_baras.gif" style="width: 550px; height: 10px; margin-top: -10px"></div>
```

Comment: post the ajax code in your question

Comment: I not have AJAX code, (not know where use)

Comment: this is pretty terrible stuff going on here.  Generally, that echo is identical, except for the hidden/shown #load.  Why not use jquery to show and hide it?  Not sure what very_long_function is but unless your calling a server you do not need ajax.  You should have the function, you also will have a non-responsive page while the very long function is running, may not be a good idea either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you architecture is wrong. You have to user JS for it.

Like next:

```
    $(function(){
       $('#load').css('display','inline');

       $.post('/very_long_function.php', {url: 'http://www.google.com'}, function(result){
           alert(result);
           $('#load').css('display','none');
       }); 
    });
```

PHP: **very_long_function.php**

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$result = very_long_function($url);
echo $result;
die;
```

Comment: Sorry my `very_long_function($url)` have 1 argument and return value, how to chenge your code ?

Comment: you can pass to server $url variable, see my updated post again

Comment: and don't forget to include jquery

Answer (score 0):

Are sure that you included jquery lib for using it . Also there is no double $$ in jquery.
Please give the html and after we will correct it.

Comment: this should be a comment dear